# SQL - Getting data from three unrelated tables in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to understand the 9th tip in http://www.orafaq.com/papers/sqltiptr.pdf

Combining three separate queries into one:

```
select name from emp where emp_no=1234;
select name from dpt where dot_no=10;
select name from cat where emp_no='RD';


select e.name, d.name, c.name
from cat c, dpt d, emp e, dual x
where NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', E.ROWId (+))
and NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', D.ROWId (+))
and NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', C.ROWId (+))
and e.emp_no(+)=1234
and d.dept_no(+)=10
and c.cat_type(+)='RD'
```

Why do we need these null value comparison in the query?

```
 NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', E.ROWId (+))
and NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', D.ROWId (+))
and NVL('x',X.DUMMY)=NVL('X', C.ROWId (+))
```

Comment: that gives the outer join something to join to...  it does look a little bit funny

Answer (score 3):

```
select name from emp where emp_no=1234
UNION ALL
select name from dpt where dot_no=10
UNION ALL
select name from cat where emp_no='RD'
```

or if you want all of them in one row:

```
SELECT (select name from emp where emp_no=1234) a,
       (select name from dpt where dot_no=10) b,
       (select name from cat where emp_no='RD') c
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: I think the OP isn't asking how to select, he's asking why its done that way in the doc.

Comment: @Randy: updated the answer. `OUTER JOIN` is still not a good solution for that issue

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty esoteric trick -- the DUAL table has one row in it, and the ROWIDs in your actual tables are also unique, so using NVL('X'.. is a way to trick the JOIN into 'relating' the unrelated records.  Then the rest of your WHERE clause applies the actual constraints that you're after.

I think zerkms's approach is more straightforward, but since you asked specifically about that tip ... HTH

Comment: thanks - makes sense. But outer join is in the following conditions also-- do we still need that? I think we might because join is on two tables? (If yes, how does join on one table field and a value works below?)

and e.emp_no(+)=1234
and d.dept_no(+)=10
and c.cat_type(+)='RD'